# Coworker made an inappropriate joke, in a work email, about me being violent at work

Tags: united-states, conflict

It was in the context of a joking back-and-forth, and this person took it too far. Without getting bogged down in details, think of something along the lines of:

> Lol. Fine, well I'll just tell everyone you said you were going to
>   [perpetrate act of workplace violence]

I generally like this person and I don't want to get him/her in trouble, but I am also concerned about this being misconstrued in a potentially monitored work email. This person apologized for the comment and I am sure it won't happen again, but I wonder whether I need to report this or do something otherwise to protect myself.

To be clear, the follow-up emails make it clear that the comment was a joke, but it still feels very icky to me. I fear preemptively trying to "report" this because I don't want to get the co-worker in trouble, but I also don't want to come under suspicion because of a misguided joke made by a coworker. Once again, the "joke" is preposterous and wouldn't, in any sense, be validated by even the most rigorous investigation of me and all of my correspondences and online activities, should I just forget it and move on or, perhaps with an overabundance of caution (given the climate we live in), should I preemptively "report" this to security and make it clear that it was a bad joke that I've been promised will never happen again?

PS: I am based in US

**Edit:** I can see this question was closed as opinion-based. I don't know how to change it because it seems to me that, on a soft site like this, most questions (including those that are not closed, and in many cases have large numbers of upvotes) are opinion-based. In any case, I think I got what I needed. Thank you to everyone who gave feedback!

Comment: Yeah, since even the most rigorous of investigations wouldn’t in any sense validate it, I’d say “forget it and move on” would probably be the best course of action. I highly doubt reporting to HR that “it was a joke and I don’t actually plan on stabbing everybody in the office” would help the situation.

Comment: "To be clear, the follow-up emails make it clear that the comment was a joke" I'm confused then why you are still worried people will take it the wrong way. That's assuming anyone is actually monitoring your emails in the first place.

Comment: @DavidK, That's a fair point. I think the worry arises from the current climate where it seems that suggestions of school/workplace violence are taken extremely seriously.

Comment: @wwyd I would say that you have to less to worry about than your coworker who mad a joke in bad taste.

Comment: @DavidK, to be fair, we were both making jokes in somewhat poor taste--it was a sarcastic, but friendly, back-and-forth between two people who know each other to be up for that kind of banter. The problem was making a joke about a hot-button issue in a situation where it could be misconstrued by someone reading it. If this were 1-on-1 and not in a traceable format like an email (e.g. in an in-person conversation), I wouldn't be posing the question.

Comment: While your work email may be monitored, your IT department has many better things to do than read random employees' emails unless you give them a reason to. No one is going to see it unless you turn it into an issue they need to investigate.

Comment: @SethR, I see what you're saying but who knows if there's some kind of  key word/words that flag emails. Thank you for the reassurance though.

Comment: Wellcome to 1984 - so much for "I don´t care about surveillance, I have nothing to hide."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in this case you let it ride and move on.  By your own words in your question, you state:

> To be clear, the follow-up emails make it clear that the comment was a
>   joke, but it still feels very icky to me.

This sounds to me as though the issue is resolved appropriately and based on my experience, I would leave it be unless it for some reason comes back around.

You also state:

> I fear preemptively trying to "report" this because I don't want to
>   get the co-worker in trouble, but I also don't want to come under
>   suspicion because of a misguided joke made by a coworker.

*Follow your instincts here*. Security and HR are there **to protect the company**.  In my experience, base on the situation you have outlined, *you do not want the HR or Security spotlight shined on you or your co-worker* for something that in the end is not that big of a deal (now that it's been addressed).

My guess is your co-worker **feels pretty dumb about this**.  Dumb that it was said, and **worse that it impact you** in an un-intended way.

Let it be.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to split this in two:

1. I feel bad about the line
2. I feel scared that when this email surface, people might read it as an evidence of my inappropriate behavior

Both issues might be addressed by you writing, in the same email thread, something along the lines of:

> I really feel that this joke is inappropriate, and hope you know that is not something I would do.

Then person would hopefully reply by supporting you.

Another way to go around it is to present email thread, with names blacked-out, to the HR or your immediate manager, to gauge whether this is potential issue for you or your coworker.

Comment: Oh yea, get HR involved - sure way to get marked down as troublemaker!